# How to open URL and take a screen shot for it?

Tags: java, image, url, web, frame

I am trying to open a given URL and then take a screen shot for it and output it as a frame background. I don't know how to complete this code.
also how can i scale the saved image to fit the frame?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, AWTException 
{ 
     URI MyURL;
     String url;
     WebView view;

     url = "http://facebook.com";
     MyURL = new URI (url);
     getDesktop().browse(MyURL);

    BufferedImage Image = ImageIO.read(new File ("C:\\Users\\hagar001\\Desktop\\OOP\\tt.jpg"));
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String web, String url) throws IOException, AWTException 
{
    if(web.equals(url))
    {
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        capture =  (BufferedImage) capture.getScaledInstance(700, 700, BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIO.write(capture, "jpg", new File ("C:\\Users\\hagar001\\Desktop\\OOP\\tt.jpg"));
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println ("Error loading the page");
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see how this code works.  There is no `main` method, and I can't see where onPageFinished is called, when, what parameters, etc.  Please provide an MCVE

Comment: in the main method i created an object of Frame type and set some properties to the jframe. 
I don't know how to send a parameters to this function, this is one of the problems too.

Comment: the screen is taken if i moved this onPageFinished to the main function but once I want to put it in this function so it take the screen shot when the web page is loaded

Comment: Please provide an MCVE

Comment: @StephenC I edit the post

Comment: I still don't see where you are calling `onPageFinished`.  Please provide this information.

Comment: @StephenC I still don't know how to call it or what parameters should I pass them to it.

Answer (score 0):

`Desktop.browse()` can not notify finishing page.
So you should wait for a moment and capture screen.

```
// ...
getDesktop().browse(MyURL);
Thread.sleep(3000);  // wait 3 seconds
onPageFinished(null, url, url);
// ...
```